# How to insert values in database using Java where number of arguments to be inserted might vary

Tags: java, sql

I am creating a function, where the user needs to provide the table name and the path of a json file where the values are stored, and it will be inserted to a database: `insertData(String tablename, String jsonFilePath)`

Now if i would have known in advance what is the number of values to be inserted, it would have been easy to create a PreparedStatement something like this:

```
String strQuery = "INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(strQuery);//prepare the SQL Query
            stmt.setString(1, "abc");//insert homeid
            stmt.setInt(2, "def");//insert featureid.
            stmt.executeQuery();//execute query
```

But since i don't know what is the tablename in advance, and the number of columns per table may vary, how do i go ahead with it because i need to create the SQL query string "strQuery" in advance where i need to put the `?`

Comment: Why do you need to create the query string beforehand?

Comment: @IsaiahvanderElst I don't need to, but even if i don't, you are saying i will be looping and adding the question marks, later? Is there any shorter and smarter way, where i can skip adding the question marks?

Comment: I don't really see a benefit in using prepared statements in this scenario. You could just generate the statement on the fly

Comment: @IsaiahvanderElst Sorry, can you show, how do i do that? Am relatively new to Java

Comment: You could write code to generate the PreparedStatement code you posted, based on what you find in the JSON.  You would use StringBuilders.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: Yes, i thought to do that, but just thought if there is some way, i can skip adding the question marks, since they may vary in number, and somewhat looks hard coded

Comment: I don't see a scenario where you'd have no idea how the data structure would be in advance. could you please give an example like why you'd have no knowledge of the table name and the number of columns etc?

Comment: Because the tablename, will be passed as an argument to my function. Since that can vary, the number of arguments can vary as well

Comment: You can build your own SQL statement and skip adding the question marks.  Just remember to put all strings in single quotation marks and get the SQL syntax absolutely correct.  I'd rather let the PreparedStatement code do the work for me.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I got you, in that case even i can skip the prepared statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the structure of the insert statement is likely to change, the statements can be generated on the fly. There's no real benefit to using prepared statements if you're not going to reuse it.  The following is an example generating the statements on the fly using a statement (as opposed to a prepared statement:

```
public boolean insert(Connection conn, String table, List<String> columns, List<String> values) throws SQLException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("INSERT INTO ");
    sb.append(table);
    sb.append(" (");

    // add columns
    Iterator<String> it = columns.iterator();
    sb.append(it.next());
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append(it.next());
    }

    sb.append(") VALUES (");

    // add values
    it = values.iterator();
    sb.append(it.next());
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(',');
        sb.append(it.next());
    }

    sb.append(");");

    // insert
    try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
        return stmt.execute(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Note that this code does not perform the proper validation. For example, an error will occur if the any of the two lists are empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a solution like this to dynamically generate the Prepared Statement (the DataField array can also be used for the setXXX):

```
public String generateStatement(String tablename, DataField[] datafields) {
    String stmt = "INSERT INTO " + tablename + " (";

    for (DataField dataField : datafields) {
        stmt += dataField.getName() + ",";
    }

    // Remove last ','
    stmt = stmt.substring(0, stmt.length() - 1);
    stmt += ") VALUES(";

    for (DataField dataField : datafields) {
        stmt += "?,";
    }

    // Remove last ','
    stmt = stmt.substring(0, stmt.length() - 1);
    stmt += ")";

    return stmt.toString();
}

public class DataField {
    private String name;
    private String value;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Improvements to be done:

- Accept several type of parameters (String, Integer, etc...). You can create an ENUM on DataField and a type on datafield to manage this.
- Check if the parameters passed to generateStatement are correct
- Use StringBuffer instead of String to generate the Prepared Statement
- Create an object to hold both the table name and the array of DataField if needed